# Get row prior to datetimeindex for conditional calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 2 dataframes `df1` and `df2`(a list of values) using `datetimeindexes`. I want to perform a conditional calculated field when the 2 `datetimeindexes` match. When they match, I would like to access the prior row `df1`.  I would like to and perform the following calc.

```
df1['calc']=df1.where(df1.index==df2, 
                      df1['High']/df1['Close'].shift(1),
                      df1.['Close']/df1['Close].shift(1))
```

here is `df1`.

```
    Open    High    Low Close   Volume
Date_Time                   
2012-08-30  9:40:00 1273.25 1273.25 1273.25 1273.25 1
2012-08-30  9:50:00 1273.25 1273.25 1273.25 1273.25 1
2012-08-30 10:00:00 1273.25 1273.25 1273.25 1273.25 2
2012-08-30 10:10:00 1274.25 1274.50 1274.25 1274.50 3
2012-08-30 10:20:00 1274.00 1274.00 1274.00 1274.00 5
```

this is the list of times in `df2`:

```
2012-08-29   2012-08-29 15:40:00
2012-08-30   2012-08-30 10:00:00
2012-08-31   2012-08-31 10:50:00
2012-09-04   2012-09-04 15:50:00
2012-09-05   2012-09-05 10:50:00
2012-09-10   2012-09-10 12:30:00
2012-09-12   2012-09-12 09:50:00
2012-09-14   2012-09-14 15:20:00
2012-09-19   2012-09-19 10:30:00
```

I tried to use `.get_loc`, `.loc`,and `.loc`.  I tried masking but that only accesses the prior row of the masked dateframe.   Thanks.

Comment: Can you be a bit clear what when wrong? " I tried masking but that only accesses the prior row of the masked dateframe." this is not so clear to me. Thank you. Also, provide the data by calling `to_dict()` to your data frames would be helpful.

Comment: There are also a couple of typos in your calc, e.g. `df1.['Close']` and `df1['Close].shift(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a terrible pandas answer using nested for loops. This was faster to write than figuring out how to compare index values between dataframes.

```
for df1_row in df1.index.tolist():
    for df2_row in df2.index.tolist():
        if df1_row == df2_row:
            row = df1.index.get_loc(df1_row)
            print(df1.iloc[row]['High'] / df1.iloc[row - 1]['Close'])
            print(df1.iloc[row]['Close'] / df1.iloc[row - 1]['Close'])
```

Output:

```
1.00078600904
1.00078600904
```

Every time I use a for loop with pandas, I imagine there's some better solution out there.

Edit:

```
df3 = df1[['High', 'Close']].iloc[ \
    (df1.index.get_loc(df1.index.intersection(df2.index)[0]) - 2):\
    df1.index.get_loc(df1.index.intersection(df2.index)[0])]
df3['Close_Div_Prev_Close'] = df3.Close/df3.shift().Close
df3['High_Div_Prev_Close'] = df3.High/df3.shift().Close
```

Output:

```
    High    Close   Close_Div_Prev_Close    High_Div_Prev_Close
date_time               
2012-08-30 09:40:00     1271.25     1271.25     NaN     NaN
2012-08-30 09:50:00     1272.25     1272.25     1.000787    1.000787
```